# When validating a form, should I assume a field is valid or invalid?

Tags: forms, language-agnostic, validation

When I write validation code for a web form, I usually assume that the content of a field is valid and attempt to prove that it is invalid. Is it a better practice to assume that the content of the field is invalid and then attempt to prove that it is valid?

A very simple example (pseudo code):

```
function isValid( formFieldValue, minLength, maxLength ) {
    valid = true;

    fieldLength = length( formFieldValue );

    if( fieldLength  < minLength ) {
        valid = false;
    }

    if( fieldLength > maxLength ) {
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Would it be better to assume that the field in question is invalid and modify my checks accordingly?

Please note - I'm not talking about XSS protection or input filtering. We can never assume that user input is safe. I am talking about validating things like minimum/maximum length or a valid e-mail address in a form field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you just talk about things like length etc. it makes no big difference. But I would ever assume that the input is invalid and prove that it's not, because I do the same with probably XSS input.

Answer (score 0):

I think that better idea is to assume wrong input and to prove validity. It's easier.

For javascript allready exists number of libraries that solves your problem.

e.g. 
Backbone.Forms https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms

jQuery validatin plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

The point is whether your all conditions run or not.

Case1: Assume that a form is valid and then check for its invalidity by checking for example 2 conditions.
Case2. Assume that a form in invalid and then check 2 conditions whether it is invalid?

In both cases you will have to check for all conditions to satisfy because you want to validate all your fields. So whether you assume it is valid or invalid at start doesn't matter we mostly check for invalidity.